# Crystal Reports - Running total excluding singular row

Tags: crystal-reports, running-count

I'm not sure the best way to phrase this, so I will try: Is there a way to count a total of distinct IDs, but exclude the IDs that only have code 1111? But include the rows that have 1111 PLUS any other codes.

| ID | CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1111 |
| 123 | 8888 |
| 456 | 1111 |
| 789 | 1111 |
| 789 | 8888 |
| 789 | 9999 |

Total (**2**) would include IDs 123 and 789.

I have not tried anything yet, just brainstormed, and feel stuck.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's tackle a simple case where you exclude rows (not groups) that contain the CODE 1111

Do a Distinct Count on a formula that returns the ID for the "good" cases and a Null value for the excluded cases. For example:

```
IF {CODE} <> "1111" Then {ID} ELSE {@Null_String}
```

To create the ***{@Null_String}*** formula, just create it and then save without any expression.

IF {ID} is a numeric column, use:

```
IF {CODE} <> "1111" Then {ID} ELSE Val({@Null_String})
```

When you shift the focus from row-level to group-level exclusion, things get more complicated. One option is to create a database View/SP or a Crystal Command that takes care of the exclusion of those groups.

Another option is to use a Crystal Reports UFL (User Function Library). Ken Hamady maintains a listing of 3rd-party Crystal Reports UFLs here. And at least one of them allows you to leverage one function in a Crystal formula to establish an in-memory table of all group values with non-1111 codes. The formula can use '***WhileReadingRecords;***' so the results can be used at the top of the report or in any other report "pass". That UFL provides another function that can directly return a count of those groups in-memory table. Or you can do a lookup for any group value and see if it in the table.

Using similar logic, you can use a subreport in the report header to establish a shared array variable with all group values that contain a non-1111 code.